# Would this be classified as a corner or a cusp?

Tags: calculus, limits, derivatives

I am teaching about differentiability in an introductory single-variable calculus course.  We went through the usual classification of points at which functions are non-differentiable into corners, cusps, and vertical tangents.  One of my students then asked a question which I'm not sure of the answer to.  Here's my write-up for the community here (using more formal language than I use in my class, of course).

We begin by defining our terms:

Let $X \subseteq \mathbf R$ and let $f: X \to \mathbf R$.  Let $c \in X$ be a point at which $f$ is continuous.  We say that $f$ is differentiable at $x=c$ if and only if $\lim_{h \to 0}\frac{f(c+h)-f(c)}{h}$ exists.

Suppose now that this limit fails to exist, so $f$ is not differentiable at $x=c$.  The limit may fail to exist for several different reasons.

If there exist $a, b \in \mathbf R$ such that $\lim_{h \to 0^+}\frac{f(c+h)-f(c)}{h}=a$ and $\lim_{h \to 0^-}\frac{f(c+h)-f(c)}{h}=b$, but $a \neq b$, then we say that $f$ has a ***corner*** at $x=c$.

If $\lim_{h \to 0^+}\frac{f(c+h)-f(c)}{h}=\pm\infty$ and $\lim_{h \to 0^-}\frac{f(c+h)-f(c)}{h}=\mp\infty$, then we say that $f$ has a ***cusp*** at $x=c$.

If $\lim_{h \to 0}\frac{f(c+h)-f(c)}{h}=\pm\infty$, then we say that $f$ has a ***vertical tangent*** at $x=c$.

Here's the question:

Suppose our function $f$ is defined by $f(x)=\begin{cases} -\arctan(x) & ,\; x \leq 0 \\ \sqrt{x} & ,\; x \gt 0 \end{cases}$

It is clear that $\lim_{h \to 0^-}\frac{f(0+h)-f(0)}{h}=-1$ and $\lim_{h \to 0^+}\frac{f(0+h)-f(0)}{h}=\infty$.  So how should we classify the failure of $f$ to be differentiable at $x=0$?

Comment: The problem here is that at the origin we have to different functions meeting each other. Your introduced definitions of a "corner" and "cusp" are based on one single $f(x)$. If you don't want to go too formal here, certainly the piecewise function is not differentiable at O but as far as qualification is concerned, I would go with the broadest interpretation regarding cusp or corner. That's my 2 cents.

Comment: @imranfat What is your "broadest interpretation" in this context?  Would you actually classify this point as a corner or a cusp, or would you just say that none of our defined terms apply, so we simply state that $f$ is not differentiable at $x=0$ and leave it at that?

Comment: Strictly I would go for the latter, but if I have to make the choice in name-giving, I would go for the cusp simply because of the infinity of the radical. Other people on this site may disagree and I am no authority here, so don't take my word for it. What I can tell you for sure that this is not the only example where a piecewise function forces you to "bend the rules" of classical definitions. What is most important for your students is to recognize that the function is not differentiable at O

Comment: @imranfat Makes sense.  I definitely agree that deciding where functions are differentiable and where they fail to be differentiable is more important than specifically classifying the failures of differentiability.  Thanks for your comments.

Comment: A cusp makes sense for curves (when two pieces of the curve meet tangentially at a point ?). Rotating your curve $(x,f(x))$ gives something similar to $(x,|x|)$ ie. what you called a corner.

Comment: @reuns I like that idea a lot.  To elaborate, would you say that at a corner, there exists a neighborhood of the point in question in which the graph of the function can be rotated and still pass the vertical line test, while at a cusp no such neighborhood can exist?

Comment: For a continuous piecewise $C^1$ curve $(x(t),y(t))$ the case $x'(t_0) = 0, y'(t_0) \ne 0$ is not a problem anymore, that leaves us with only 3 problematic cases : the curve goes to infinity, or it has a corner or a cusp.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would classify this as a corner.

This is because "corners" and "cusps" are usually properties of the graph, rather than the function, and they are invariant by rigid movement of the plane. (And if you rotate a little the graph of your fucntion you get a corner according your definition.)

More precisely, I would classify vertical tangecies as regular points of the graph (vertical tangecies are in fact regular $C^1$ points if you change cohordinate system of $\mathbb R^2$). While corners and cusps as singular points. Corners are those singular points where we have two different tangent lines and cusps are singular points where we have one tangent line.

In terms of functions, I would say:

Corner: if the graph of the function has two different left/right tangent lines

Vertical: if the graph of the function has a vertical tangent and the left/right limit have different sign

Cusp: if the graph of the function has a vertical tangent and the left/right limit have the same sign.

---

You may also want to have a look of the wiki page 
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cusp_(singularity)